# how to show only 4 rows and continue updating

Tags: php, html, mysqli, nodes, server-sent-events

I create a table name, attack in the database consist of 4 columns id,countrysrc,countrydst and time
let say for example,
1 singapore malaysia 1200pm
2 indonesia india 1234 pm

I created the php script to get the countrysrc and countrydst at the now time. The I use the event source to stream data from the php script. When the time is 1200pm, the Singapore data will appear, if it 1234, the Indonesia will appear.My website will continue showing data at every time. I can see a long rows of data in the element tab. However,  i want to view only 4 rows of data being updated continuously just like the fireeye website.https://www.fireeye.com/cyber-map/threat-map.html. At the top center, you can see that at the first time, 1 rows of data will appear until there are 4 rows. When there are 4 rows of data, they will be changed to new data. However mine is different from that website. The data keep on updating and it become like this.

[image]

[image]

When you compare to the fireeye website, it is like this

[image]

I want to achieve the fireeye website. The reason is why I want to achieve this is because, the performance will be affected if I use mine in the project.

my code is found below..

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
}
pre {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 500px;
    height: 62px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #95B9C7;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #87CEFA;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<pre id="result"></pre>

<script>
const result = document.getElementById("result");
if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("shownewattacksqli1.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        //Redefine node at each message event
        const node = document.createTextNode(event.data + "\n");
        result.insertBefore(node, result.firstChild);    
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

php code

```
<?php
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        $dbhost     = "xxx";
        $dbusername     = "xx";
        $dbpassword     = "xx";
        $dbname     = "xx";
        $nowtime = time();
        $con = mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die ('Error in connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

        //Select the particular database and link to the connection
        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname ) or die('Select dbase error '. mysqli_error());
        //Make A SQL Query and link to the connection

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `countrysrc`,`countrydst` FROM `countryattack` WHERE `time` =".$nowtime. " LIMIT 1");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "data: [X] NEW ATTACK: FROM " . $row["countrysrc"]. " TO " . $row["countrydst"]. " \n\n";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

My question is how to show only 4 rows of data being dynamically updated. I do not want to modify the sql query to limit 4 rows. That is not what I want. I want exactly like the fireeye cyber threat map. Is it possible??? If it is possible, please help thank you..

If you want to try it out, create a database and input data into the table.. I have the script for you to input data to the table and you can run the php scriptusing php.exe Please use later time and then u can see data at that time

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "netwitness";
$dbname = "abdpractice";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

for ($i=0;$i  <=3600;$i++) {

    $countryarr = array("UNITED STATES", "INDIA", "SINGAPORE","MALAYSIA","COLOMBIA","THAILAND","ALGERIA","ENGLAND","CANADA","CHINA", "SAUDI ARABIA");
    $length = sizeof($countryarr)-1;
    $random = rand(0,$length);
    $random1 = rand(0,$length);

    $random_srccountry = $countryarr[$random];
    $random_dstcountry = $countryarr[$random1];
    $time = 1507088401 + $i;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO countryattack (id,countrysrc, countrydst, time)
    VALUES ('$i','$random_srccountry','$random_dstcountry','$time')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($("#result p)) >= 4) {
  $("#result p:last").remove();
  // append new row here
}
```

You will need to check whether rows already have 4. If more or have 4, remove the latest and append again.

You will need to add elementTag to your every new created data before insert into UI by changing below jQuery

```
result.insertBefore(node, result.firstChild);
```

to

```
result.insertBefore("<p>"+node"</p>", result.firstChild);
```

Wrap up

```
if (count($("#result p)) >= 4) {
  $("#result p:last").remove();
  // append new row here
}
 result.insertBefore("<p>"+node"</p>", result.firstChild);
```

Above code using jQuery - haven't test. But, probably like that

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
        background-image: url("background.jpg");
    }
    pre {
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        width: 500px;
        height: 62px;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #95B9C7;
        border-style: solid;
        border-top-color: #87CEFA;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
    <pre id="result"></pre>

    <script>
    const result = document.getElementById("result");
    if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource("shownewattacksqli1.php");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            //Redefine node at each message event
            const node = document.createTextNode(event.data + "\n");
            if (count($("#result p)) >= 4) {
                $("#result p:last").remove();
            }
            result.insertBefore("<p>"+node"</p>", result.firstChild);    
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
    }
```

Comment: I understand ur statement, but however, where did u get the log div and the count from

Comment: can you erm provide a better answer

Comment: refer my updated again answer. you will need to add <p> or <div> when creating it to append into code.. once you have the <p> or <div>. you just change " div:last " to "yourelement:last" @Azhar

Comment: @Azhar refer above